# vuetify How to set content to tabs v-tabs-items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new with vuetify, I want to set two Tables to vuetify.js tabs but when I set two tables into tabs show me only one table and doesn't change content. what is wrong with my code. thanks.

```
<v-card>
                            <v-tabs v-model="tab"
                                    background-color="deep-purple accent-4"
                                    centered
                                    dark
                                    icons-and-text>
                                <v-tabs-slider></v-tabs-slider>

                                <v-tab href="#subscribe">
                                    Subscribe
                                    <v-icon>mdi-phone</v-icon>
                                </v-tab>

                                <v-tab href="#contact">
                                    Contact
                                    <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                                </v-tab>
                            </v-tabs>

                            <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
                                <v-tab-item
                                        :key="1"
                                        :value="subscribe">
                                    <v-card flat>
                                        <v-card-text> 
                                            <v-data-table ....></v-card-text>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-tab-item>
                                <v-tab-item
                                        :key="2"
                                        :value="contact">
                                    <v-card flat>
                                        <v-card-text> <v-data-table ...></v-card-text>
                                    </v-card>
                                </v-tab-item>
                            </v-tabs-items>
                        </v-card>
```

Comment: please add the code of  <v-data-table ....> and also show the data part. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to bind `v-tab-item`'s `value` to the `subscribe` and `contact` properties, but set `v-tab-item`'s `value` to be a plain string "subscribe" and "contact".

Just remove colon in front of `:value`

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ysemeniuk/pen/JjProMB)

Comment: Also want to stress necessity of adding `href` prop to `v-tab` this way -
 ` :href="'#' + tabName"` , otherwise `tab` will default to using indexes, rather than string values.